# Searching with Google Maps from desktop then transfering route to phone

Tags: google-maps, android, gps

I use Google Maps on my phone for transit instructions and to find my way around. The problem is it's hard to work with a small screen and typing in complex addresses is a pain. I noticed sometimes when I use Google Maps on my desktop the route sort of syncs with the Google Maps on my phone. For example on my desktop if I search `1234 Fake Street Vancouver` if I start typing in `1234` on my phone the list sometimes auto populates. When does this happen? Is there a better way of doing this? I noticed in Google Maps when used on my desktop has the option to "Send" to Email, Car and GPS. Is there an option to send it to my phone, since my phone does have a GPS? [image: google maps send link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now baked in to the latest version of Google Maps. Just look up an address, then click the "send to device" link and choose your Android device. Then open the notification on your phone.

[image: screen shot]

This has been around for a little while for iOS.

(via [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/google-maps-can-now-send-directions-from-your-desktop-t-1717230486))

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything but login to Google on your desktop and phone.

As long as you login to your Google account on your desktop before you search for directions, Google Maps will automatically store your recent directions in My Places. This works in most browsers and on Windows, Mac or iPad.

From your phone, or any other device, login to your Google account, if your app doesn't auto login, open Google Maps and look under My Places. On my Android phone, my recent directions show up in My Places->Recent and My Places -> Directions.

If you want to save directions more permanently, you can open them, then save them to My Maps using the button at the bottom of the directions listing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I get directions from my desktop to my phone (which is an iPhone, if it matters):

1. Some prerequisites: install Google Chrome on both your desktop and phone, and sign in with your Google account and  enable [tab syncing](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582?hl=en).
2. On the desktop computer, go to Google Maps and get the exact directions you want.
3. On the phone, open Chrome and tap New Tab, then the icon for Other Devices.
4. You should see a heading for your desktop computer, and a list of open tabs on your desktop. One of those open tabs will be Google Maps with your directions. Tap it.
5. The directions should load on your phone, formatted for mobile. You may also get an Open in Google Maps button, which you can tap to transfer the directions from Chrome to the Google Maps app.

This technique works for getting any webpage from desktop to mobile.

Answer (score 1):

If you use android, there is this really handy app and browser plugin which is called Google chrome to Phone. Once found a page (or navigation plan), you simply click the icon in chrome, and the link will be sent to your phone, which wil act according to your link.

I use it all the time and it's really handy!

[Extention for chrome from the chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-chrome-to-phone-ex/oadboiipflhobonjjffjbfekfjcgkhco?hl=nl)

[The app for your phone.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone&hl=nl)

Answer (score 1):

If you click the cog icon at the bottom, and then click "Share or embed map", you get a link. If you email the link to yourself and open it on your phone (or turn in into a QR code and scan it on your phone), you can choose to open the directions in the Google maps app. The great thing about this method is it can transfer a custom route you made when dragging the route to make it go a certain way.

**Update Sep 2016**

Now, you have to click the menu button in the top left instead of a cog. However, it no longer preserves any custom route you make (at least for the Android app), unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Star" the address on the PC 
1. Go to google.com/maps
2. Search for an address 
3. Star the address (Just to the left of the address in the left column)
4. Then go to the Google Maps application on your phone
5. Top Left, Select "My Places" -- it should be there (after a syc)

Google has this to say about "My Places":
When you star an item, it appears on your maps and is listed in My Places.
Using your phone? Just click the Local tab on www.google.com to see starred items and quickly find hours, reviews, phone numbers, and more.